# Which is important senior (last) author or first author if I have the choice?

Tags: publications, research-process

I am currently postdoc and I worked on a project of my idea and worked most of it. I do not know should I choose the first author considering that I did most of the work or senior (last )author as it is my idea and will be good thing in future.
I will be corresponding author in both situation

Comment: Sorry, but "senior author" is unfamiliar to me. What does it mean? Is it field specific?

Comment: Last author, I work in life sciences, usually called this

Comment: Isn't that generally the PI? The one that funds the lab?

Comment: Generally, first author is most prestigious. If you deserve it, you should of course be the first author. Last author indicates a PI role. It's good to have that too but not as valuable as first author.

Comment: I am still indecisive  because It is different case scenario, the project is online collaboration that I was responsible for. It was my idea and I had the team. I am also PI.

Comment: I will not infrequently be writing a paper and the project PI.  I could easily be first or last author, but would always and without hesitation choose first author.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be flattering to your field, but no reflection on you is implied.

If your field sort of expects that no one in the lab does anything meaningful except the PI and everyone else just basks in the glory, then choose last author. I'd be surprised, however, that you are permitted to do this if you work for a PI.

If your field sort of expects that the PI is always added to the papers from the lab even though they only contribute grant writing and financial support but almost no intellectual content, and that the first author is really the one that does the work, then choose first author.

I actually prefer alphabetical listing, and require that everyone listed actually contribute IP to the paper, but that doesn't always hold sway in the "real" world, and I've deviated from that when it was clear that someone in particular was really driving the ideas, then listing them first. Luckily I was in a field that supports that.

But, unless you know otherwise, I'd guess that first author is more likely to imply the person who is primarily responsible for the work, its direction, and its content.

Comment: It is different case scenario, the project is online collaboration that I did. It was my idea and I had the team. It is not PI lab

Comment: Still, it is what will pop into the heads of readers when they look at it. What are their assumptions? It can be very field specific as I've surmised from reading a lot of questions here about authorship disputes. Note that those reader assumptions may not be either accurate or rational.